# Analyze EPS metadata - Distinguish between Freehand EPS and Illustrator EPS

Tags: file, header, metadata, adobe-illustrator, eps

I want to analyze a few thousand EPS files and sort them according to their application in which they have been created (in my case Freehand or Illustrator).

I know that the the information is stored in the file header (%%Creator), but how can I analyze it thoughout all files?

I am looking for a tool to analyze the files and to give me a txt or csv file...

**I already tried the following:**

- Windows Explorer --> shows lots of properties, but not the %%Creator
- Adobe Bridge --> shows file metadata, but only of single files
- Adobe Bridge, [MetaData Script](http://www.ps-bridge-scripts.talktalk.net/) (See the Bridge section -- Extract Metadata) --> the script should export all metadata, but doesn't do it's job for all files...
- pdfinfo.exe --> part of [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html), I assumed, if it can analyze PDF files, it may also analyze EPS, but does't...
- Ghostscript --> I searched Google, but did not find a solution
- ImageMagick  --> I searched Google, but did not find a solution
- ExifTool --> although it seems to be powerful, I could not manage to get the information intended

I am happy for any help!

Best regards
Hape

Comment: I know that tool recommendations aren't welcome here. However, I think this question is valid as it doesn't ask about "the best tool for some task" in general, but is specific in what function is needed and shows some previous effort of the OP to sort out existing tools.

Comment: yes the recommendation is not the main goal for my question. I am just looking for a solution to analyze the metadata of many files...

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple script here a python 2.x script for example:

```
import glob

for fname in glob.glob('*.eps'):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        line = fp.readline()
        if not '%!PS' in line:
            continue
        print "-- %s --" % fname
        line = fp.readline().strip()
        while line.startswith("%"):
            if line.startswith("%%"):
                print line
            line = fp.readline().strip()
```

**Edity:** Updated script to understand windows style EPS previews. And relaxed the metadata requirements to match spec better

Comment: any other solution beside python scripting?

Comment: @Hape well you could implement the same in nearly any language what would you accept wsh, bash, c, c++, visual basic etc etc. The reason metadata handlers dont see this is that its not os metadata. anyway since your asking on stackoverflow i kind of assumed you know how to program/script. If not then your question should be on superuser.

Comment: well... i am not a developer but i can handle stuff like VBA and scripts. Maybe the questions would have been better placed on SuperUser... the limitation for me is also my desktop PC at work. I can't run stuff like Python on the PC due to admin restrictions... Would that script be also possible with some Excel VBA or maybe command line system tools?